# Metal resource "purgeable state" mechanics

Tags: objective-c, gpu, rendering, metal, metalkit

I'm working in Objective-C, but this question is ubiquitous to swift too (I think). If I have buffer `id<MTLBuffer> my_buffer` and a render command currently queued on the GPU that reads from `my_buffer`. If I set `my_buffer`'s purgeable state to be empty, i.e.

```
[my_buffer setPurgeableState:MTLPurgeableStateEmpty];
```

BEFORE or DURING the command being processed on the GPU, what will happen? Will the GPU still use the resource without a problem and then discard it once it is done? Or will it not know that that buffer exists anymore? Does `purgeableState` even affect the device's allocation of memory?

If this is not the case, how do I set a buffer to discard it's memory when there are no outstanding render command queued that reference it (but the program is oblivious to whether or not there are outstanding render commands referencing it)?

Comment: An in-flight command buffer cannot reference any resources other than `NonVolatile`. Otherwise, you are basically invoking an undefined behavior. If you want to use purgable states, it's your job to track which resources are used by in-flight command buffers and make sure that all of them are non-volatile before a command buffer is submitted.

Comment: @Spo1ler Cool, I started implementing a reference counter on CPU. However, Is there any way to attach meta-data to a command buffer. I want to set an index to each command buffer so when it completes, I can decrement the buffer associated with that index

Comment: In general, no, you shouldn't "attach metadata" to random Objective C objects. If you really need to do this, you can use `NSDictionary` or, better yet `NSMapTable`. But I would just pass the index as part of the closure that you would pass to `addCompletedHandler`.

Comment: Actually, what problem are you trying to solve with purgable states?

Comment: I have already solved it, but for context i wanted to nicely abstract resizing `MTLBuffer`s by making a class that has two revolving `MTLBuffer*`s. When resizing, we format the back buffer while drawing from the front until the back is prepared. Once the back is done (reallocated) we swap buffers and draw (and edit) the new one. I could not just purge the old buffer because there may be frames in flight that read from it.

Comment: To solve this, I just kept a counter on each `MTLBuffer` that track how many frames in flight read from that buffer. Then I set a handler on the end of each frame draw command that check if a resize (edit) has occurred and if there are zero frames referencing the old buffer. If that number is zero, the old sized buffer is finally purged to save space.

Comment: are you reusing those later?

Comment: no once they are purged, and all of the frames in flight that reference it have finished I do not use that buffer anymore. It is after all of an obsolete size because we resize the buffer.

Comment: then why bother with purgeability? Just let the reference go

Comment: If I let the reference go will the space still be allocated on the device??

Comment: No. You don't need to manage purgeability for that. Purgeable state is for resources that your application might want to let go because it can easily restore them, such as textures that can be streamed from storage, when the memory pressure increases.